# Why does timeout not work within a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, timeout

I tried to kill a process if it exceeds more than a few seconds.

The following works just fine when I run it in the terminal.

```
timeout 2 sleep 5
```

But when I have a script -

```
#!/bin/bash
timeout 2 sleep 5
```

it says

> timeout: command not found

Why so? What is the workaround?

--EDIT--

On executing type timeout, it says -

> timeout is a shell function

Comment: What do you get if you run `type timeout` in shell?

Comment: @user657592 which bash version you are using ? and also check `/usr/bin/timeout` exists or not

Comment: Is that the only `timeout` you get if you run `type -a timeout`? In general you will need to export the function if you have it implemented somewhere to use it in a script, but like @RahulPatil mentioned timeout is usually just a c function unless you have some other implementations.

Comment: @BroSlow - The same. `timeout is a shell function`

Comment: @user657592 Add `export -f timeout` to your `.bashrc` or wherever you have it implemented. And then re-source that init file (e.g. with `source .bashrc`) and try running the script again.

Comment: @user657592 can you provide which version of coreutils you are using `rpm -qa | grep coreutil` if it is < `coreutils 8.12.197-032bb` then it may be function created and you will need to update coreutils to use `timeout` binary.

Comment: @BroSlow - `bash: export: timeout: not a function`

Comment: @Rahul Patil - coreutils-5.97-34.el5

Comment: need to update coreutils package => `coreutils 8.12.197-032bb`

Comment: Are you sure you exported it from the same source file that contained the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's seems your environment `$PATH` variable does not include `/usr/bin/` path or may be `timeout` binary exists in somewhere else.

So just check path of timeout command using :

```
command -v timeout
```

and use absolute path in your script

**Ex.**

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/timeout 2 sleep 5
```

**Update 1#**

As per your update in question, it is function created in your shell. you can use absolute path in your script as mentioned in above example.

**Update 2#**
`timeout` command added from coreutils version => `8.12.197-032bb`, If GNU timeout is not available you can use expect (Mac OS X, BSD, ... do not usually have GNU tools and utilities by default).

```
################################################################################
# Executes command with a timeout
# Params:
#   $1 timeout in seconds
#   $2 command
# Returns 1 if timed out 0 otherwise
timeout() {

    time=$1

    # start the command in a subshell to avoid problem with pipes
    # (spawn accepts one command)
    command="/bin/sh -c \"$2\""

    expect -c "set echo \"-noecho\"; set timeout $time; spawn -noecho $command; expect timeout { exit 1 } eof { exit 0 }"    

    if [ $? = 1 ] ; then
        echo "Timeout after ${time} seconds"
    fi

}
```

**Example:**

```
timeout 10 "ls ${HOME}"
```

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43340/how-to-introduce-timeout-for-shell-scripting)

Comment: which bash version you are using ? and also check `/usr/bin/timeout` exists or not

Comment: Using the absolute path does not help. It then says - /usr/bin/timeout: No such file or directory found

Comment: in your script, at the beginning

Comment: Now, it says this - `Starting AutoMATCH program
alling Main-dispatch-ex program
filename:`